# Get random item after applying strlen in for loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, strlen

I'm trying to get a random element of an array after applying strlen within the loop **FOR** to see that words are greater than 5 characters, but at the moment I do not get the expected result.

My code is as follows:

```
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");

for ($i=0; $i < count($input); $i++) {

   if(strlen($input[$i]) > 5)
   {
      $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);
      echo $input[$rand_keys];
   }
}
```

but failed at the time to get the random element and I returned several, besides not even function applies strlen

As I can get a random array element after applying strlen to verify that element is greater than 5 characters?

Thanks friends.

Comment: I don't quite get what you want to do here. Just get a random element? One which is longer than 5 characters? Please show what you get now and what you expect to get.

Comment: Hi.
At the moment I'm getting this

http://i.imgur.com/yeQxHaF.jpg

And the only thing I have is a random element array but that is more than 5 characters.

Answer (score 2):

First, create a new array that only contains the elements longer than 5 characters, using [`array_filter()`](https://secure.php.net/array_filter):

```
$filteredInput = array_filter($input, function ($str) {
    return strlen($str) > 5;
});
```

Then, use [`array_rand()`](https://secure.php.net/array_rand) as you were originally thinking:

```
$randomElement = $filteredInput[array_rand($filteredInput, 1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make new array with element which length more that 5, and randomize by shuffle function

```
$res = array_filter($input, function ($i) { return strlen($i) > 5; });
shuffle($res);
```

if you want only one element, you can take it by `$elem = array_shift($res)`

[demo](https://eval.in/583438)

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($input); $i++){

    $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);
    if (strlen($input[$rand_keys]) > 5){
        echo $input[$rand_keys];
    }

}
```

Like this?

Comment: I returned several elements. Thanks for your help. http://i.imgur.com/5Y0TWxu.jpg